# Dynamodb: Update an attribute used as sort key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

What would happen if an attribute used as sortKey has its value changed?

For instance, suppose I have a table products, I would use the ID as the partitionkey and the status of the product as sortkey, the status of the product is stored as an attribute of the product also, if I update the status of the product, Dynamodb will update the sortKey automatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't change the primary key (hash and/or sort keys) of a record in DDB.

[UpdateItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html) only allows for attributes to be changed.

**Edit: what would happen is that you get a new record added with the new sort key.  But the original would also be there.**

Best you could do would be to delete the record and re-add it with the new sort key.

Possibly using the new transaction support...

Unless you're using a Global Table.

Comment: this was a surprise to me because of all those examples with status in the sortkey...
Is the expectation to have multiple items and then interpret all the items after a query? 
Or is the standard pattern to delete and recreate

Comment: What's the problem or constraint specifically if I am using a Global Table and a transaction that entails deleting existing item and adding new item with updated primary key?

Comment: @WebUser I don't understand your comment, perhaps you should ask a new question.

Comment: @Charles you added a caveat at the end of your answer _Unless you're using a Global Table_, and my comment was to get clarification on what that implied.